# heartbeat failed for group because it's rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

What's the exact reason to have heartbeat failure for group because it's rebalancing ? What's the reason for rebalance where all the consumers in group are up ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Heartbeats are the basic mechanism to check if all consumers are still up and running. If you get a heartbeat failure because the group is rebalancing, it indicates that your consumer instance took too long to send the next heartbeat and was considered dead and thus a rebalance got triggered.

If you want to prevent this from happening, you can either increase the timeout (`session.timeout.ms`), or make sure your consumer sends heartbeat more often (`heartbeat.interval.ms`). Heartbeats are basically embedded in `poll()`, thus, you need to make sure you call poll frequently enough. This can usually be achieved by limit the number of records a single poll returns via `max.poll.records` (to shorten the time it takes to process all data that got fetched).

**Update**

Since Kafka 0.10.1, heartbeats are sent in a background thread, and not when `poll()` is called (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread). In this new design, configuration `session.timeout.ms` and `heartbeat.interval.ms` are still the same. Additionally, there is `max.poll.interval.ms` that determines how often `poll()` must be called. If you miss to call `poll()` within `max.poll.interval.ms`, the heartbeat thread assume that the processing thread died, and will send a leave-group-request that will trigger a rebalance, and the heartbeat thread will stop sending heartbeats afterwards. If you processing thread is ok but just slow, the next call to `poll()` will initiate another rebalance to re-join the group again.

For more details, cf. [Difference between session.timeout.ms and max.poll.interval.ms for Kafka >= 0.10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730126/difference-between-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms-for-kafka-0-10-0/39759329#39759329)

Comment: Can you tell me what should be done in the updated case to avoid the same?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Maybe ask a new question and elaborate in more detail?

Comment: Can you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753274/kafka-consumer-group-rebalancing

Comment: If this answer is correct, the error/warning message is very misleading. It should be sth. like: "Rebalancing because Heartbeat failed". If a heartbeat fails because it's rebalancing (+-consumer, upscaling, downscaling) - who cares?

Comment: "Returned in heartbeat requests when the coordinator has begun rebalancing the group. This indicates to the client that it should rejoin the group" sounds to me like "rebalancing -> heartbeat fail" and not the other way round.
https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/4d598055dab7da99e41bfcceffa8462b32931cdd/kafka/errors.py#L330