# Kafka Consumer group rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka consumer group management for processing my messages.

The processing time for my messages vary from one another. So I have set the max poll interval to 20 min for max records of 20. And I'm using 5 partition and 5 consumer instances with default config values apart from the above two.

But still I'm getting the following error intermittently:

```
[Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=amc_dashboard_analytics] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
```

The understanding is that rebalancing won't occur unless poll is not called before max poll interval is reached as written in consumer config Docs. But for me rebalancing occurs before 20 minutes only.

Also after few hours of running, all the assigned consumers just leave saying "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing" and do not join back again(Ideally should join back again).

Am I missing something here? Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Heartbeats are the basic mechanism to check if all consumers are still up and running. If you get a heartbeat failure because the group is rebalancing,

Comment: it indicates that your consumer instance took too long to send the next heartbeat and was considered dead and thus a rebalance got triggered

Comment: @DeV but why is it taking time to send heartbeat. What I read was consumer keep on sending heartbeats in a parallel thread separate from max poll interval processing thread.

Comment: A rebalance will also occur when consumers join or leave the group.

Comment: @Nobita I added some possible reasons to cannot send heartbeat to broker. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason of rebalance is expiring `session.timeout.ms` without sending heartbeat. You can consider to increase this consumer config.

From Kafka docs:

> **heartbeat.interval.ms**: The expected time between heartbeats to the
>   consumer coordinator when using Kafka's group management facilities.
>   Heartbeats are used to ensure that the consumer's session stays active
>   and to facilitate rebalancing when new consumers join or leave the
>   group. The value must be set lower than session.timeout.ms, but
>   typically should be set no higher than 1/3 of that value. It can be
>   adjusted even lower to control the expected time for normal
>   rebalances. (default: 3000)

---

> **session.timeout.ms**: The timeout used to detect client failures when
>   using Kafka's group management facility. The client sends periodic
>   heartbeats to indicate its liveness to the broker. If no heartbeats
>   are received by the broker before the expiration of this session
>   timeout, then the broker will remove this client from the group and
>   initiate a rebalance. Note that the value must be in the allowable
>   range as configured in the broker configuration by
>   group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms. (default: 10000)

You can check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) for more information.

Even if heartbeat is sent in fixed time intervals via separate thread, in some cases heartbeat cannot be sent to broker in `session.timeout.ms`. Some of the possible reasons of this situation is:

- Network problem
- stop-the-world garbage collection in consumer or broker sides

Comment: What is "stop-the-world garbage collection"?

Comment: @Nobita "Stop-the-world means that the JVM is stopping the application from running to execute a GC. When stop-the-world occurs, every thread except for the threads needed for the GC will stop their tasks. The interrupted tasks will resume only after the GC task has completed. GC tuning often means reducing this stop-the-world time."  [link](https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-java-garbage-collection)

Comment: Also could memory be a reason for heartbeat failure?

Comment: @Nobita Yes. I experienced this kind of situation in production. If memory used by JVM (-XmX) is not enough, it leads more frequent GC. And during GC, threads including heartbeat cannot be run as expected. I suggest you to monitor GC logs with this JVM opitons to be sure:   ` -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails
 -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc:</path/to/file.txt>`   By the way as I mentioned in the answer, my advise is to simply increasing `session.timeout.ms`  as workaround until diagnosing main reason.

Comment: And on what basis should I set the value for session.timeout.ms, like what would be the ideal value?

Comment: @Nobita this config wil affect failure detection time. So it's totaly up to your needs. Maybe you can set it to 30 seconds and then monitor. (If detecting client failure up to 30 seconds is okay for you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209988/discussion-between-nobita-and-h-c-t).