# "Commit failed for offsets" while committing offset asynchronously

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer from which I am consuming data from a particular topic and I am seeing below exception. I am using `0.10.0.0` kafka version.

```
LoggingCommitCallback.onComplete: Commit failed for offsets= {....}, eventType= some_type, time taken= 19ms, error= org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

I added these two extra consumer properties but still it didn't helped:

```
session.timeout.ms=20000
max.poll.records=500
```

I am committing offsets in a different background thread as shown below:

```
kafkaConsumer.commitAsync(new LoggingCommitCallback(consumerType.name()));
```

What does that error mean and how can I resolve it? Do I need to add some other consumer properties?

Comment: It means you haven't called poll before the session timeout. I think your easiest option is to upgrade to 0.10.2 or higher where heartbeats are now sent in a background thread instead of happening only when poll is called. Otherwise, consider lowering max.poll.records to a value that lets you're program work. Using the upgraded client with a 0.10.0.0 broker should work though so I think it's easier.

Comment: I  can't upgrade at this moment so the only option I have is lowering `max.poll.records` you mean to say right?

Comment: Default `session.timeout.ms` is 10000 and default `max.poll.records` is 500.  What values did you try? Also, for `0.10.2.x` you should consider increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` instead of `session.timeout.ms`. It should help to measure the time between two consecutive `poll()` calls to find a good configuration value.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I tried with these two `session.timeout.ms=20000 and 
max.poll.records=500`. For now I am stuck with `0.10.0.0`.

Comment: Did you measure the time between two consecutive poll() calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lower max.poll.records. You'll get smaller batches of data but there more frequent calls to poll that will result will help keep the session alive.