# Kafka - Consume until empty

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use-case where it is paramount to not continue until all consumer records in a `KafkaConsumer` have been fetched. In this use-case there will be nothing going into the pipeline. What is the proper way to assure that there absolutely positively is nothing at all left to fetch?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right way to be doing it? Seems like you're make a streaming solution into a batch one?

Comment: It's for when (if) our gateway has gone done and the messages haven't yet made it to Cassandra, then we want to consume the messages in the queue to find our last issued revision number.

Comment: If you know that no new data is appended, you can get the end of the log via `Consumer#endOffsets` and terminate reading when `Consumer#position` reaches the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka is designed to handle infinite streams of data, so the "consume all" means only that nobody sends any data for some period of time (1 minute), 1 hour, etc. - it's up to you.

You can use something like (pseudocode):

```
int emptyCount = 0;
while (true) {
   records = Consumer.poll(500);
   if (records.empty()) {
      emptyCount++;
      if (emptyCount >= 100) {
         break;
      }
      continue;
   }
   emptyCount = 0;
   ...process records...
}
```

you can tune timeout in poll & number of empty cycles to reach necessary wait period.

Comment: Hm, this might work. Right now I'm looking at seekToBeginning/seekToEnd and then using position to calculate if the two are the same and treating that as the stream being empty but this might be semantically incorrect, I don't know.

Comment: What is the semantic difference between doing this and calling poll with a long timeout? As said, nothing is being inputted into Kafka while this check is being performed.

Comment: If you call `poll` with timeout longer than heartbeat, then your consumer will be considered dead.

Comment: Please note that data stays in topic until they expire - it could be days by default

Comment: I just need to fetch everything that was in the message queue (primary concern: guaranteeing that everything is fetched). The scenario I'm trying to solve is: gateway (GW) issues a revision number, sends it to Kafka, GW dies and consumes _everything_ held in Kafka on start-up to ensure that it doesn't re-issue an already issued revision number. The GW might go down and back up in milliseconds so I just want to be sure that I capture the last thing sent from the GW and am concerned it might not have made it to Kafka. So "emptiness" might be the wrong concept.

Comment: In this case you can try to use compacted topics

Comment: @AlexOtt "If you call poll with timeout longer than heartbeat, then your consumer will be considered dead." -- this is only true for older Kafka versions. Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730126/difference-between-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms-for-kafka-0-10-0/39759329#39759329

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `kafka-console-consumer`, you can specify `timeout-ms` argument to define how long it will wait until it is considered to be no more message coming.

```
--timeout-ms <Integer: timeout_ms>      If specified, exit if no message is    
                                          available for consumption for the    
                                          specified interval.
```