# Suspending Camel KafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

My app has N instance running. The number of instances is always greater than the number of Kafka partitions. E.g. 6 instances of a consumer-group, consuming from 4 Kafka partitions... so, only 4 of the instances are *actually* consuming at any point.

In this context *can I suspend a Kafka consumer Camel route, without causing Kafka to attempt to re-balance to other potential consumers*? My understanding is that the suspended route would stop polling, causing the other to pick up the load.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Camel but a Kafka question. The **rebalancing is handled by Kafka** and triggered whenever a consumer explicitly leaves the consumer group or silently dies (does no more sending heartbeats).

Kafka 2.3 introduced a new feature called "[Static Membership](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances)" to avoid rebalancing just because of a consumer restart.

But in your case (another consumer must take the load of a leaving consumer) I think **Kafka must trigger a rebalancing** over all consumers due to the protocol used.

See also [this article](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2) for a quite deep dive into rebalancing and its trade-offs between availability and fault-tolerance.

**Edit due to comments**

If you want to avoid rebalancing, I think you would have to increase both `session.timeout.ms` (heartbeat interval) and `max.poll.interval.ms` (processing timeout).

But even if you set them very high I guess it would not work reliably because route suspension could still happen just before a heartbeat (simply bad timing).

See [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730126/difference-between-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms-for-kafka-0-10-0) for the difference between `session.timeout.ms` and `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should rephrase: if a consumer has no heartbeat, or if it does not poll, Kafka will try to re-balance. This implication seems to be that I cannot suspend my Camel route (in circuit-breaker fashion) unless I increase my "maxPollIntervalMs" on the consumer to a high-enough number. True?

Comment: And, @burki thanks for the links. I did not know about static membership.

Comment: I extended my answer a bit because there are two different "timeout" settings