# Spring kafka idlebetweenpolls is always triggering partition rebalance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to use the idle between polls mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setIdleBetweenPolls-long-)  to slow down the consumption rate, i also use the max.poll.interval.ms to double the idle between polls, but its always triggering partition rebalance, any idea what is the problem?
[Edit]
I have 5 hosts and i'm setting concurrency level to 1
[Edit 2]
I was setting the idle between polls to 5 min and max.poll.interval.ms to 10 min i also noticed this log "About to close the idle connection from 105 due to being idle for 540012 millis".
I decreased the idle between polls to 10 sec and the issue disappeared, any idea why?

```java
 private ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> dlqConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configurationProperties = commonConfigs();

        DlqConfiguration dlqConfiguration = kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getDlq();

        final Integer idleBetweenPollInterval = dlqConfiguration.getIdleBetweenPollInterval()
                .orElse(DLQ_POLL_INTERVAL);

        final Integer maxPollInterval = idleBetweenPollInterval * 2; // two times the idleBetweenPoll, to prevent re-balancing
        logger.info("Setting max poll interval to {} for DLQ", maxPollInterval);

        overrideIfRequired(DQL_CONSUMER_CONFIGURATION, configurationProperties, ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollInterval);

        dlqConfiguration.getMaxPollRecords().ifPresent(maxPollRecords ->
                overrideIfRequired(DQL_CONSUMER_CONFIGURATION, configurationProperties, ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords)
        );


        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configurationProperties);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`<time to process last polled records> + <idle between polls>` must be less than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

**EDIT**

There is logic in the container to make sure we never exceed the max poll interval:

```java
idleBetweenPolls = Math.min(idleBetweenPolls,
        this.maxPollInterval - (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.lastPoll)
                - 5000); // NOSONAR - less by five seconds to avoid race condition with rebalance
```

I can't reproduce the issue with this...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63411124Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63411124Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63411124", topics = "so63411124")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory,
                    KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {

        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(300000L);
        return args -> {
            while (true) {
                template.send("so63411124", "foo");
                Thread.sleep(295000);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so63411124").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=debug
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=600000
```

If you can provide a small example like this that exhibits the behavior you describe, I will take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: thats what we have max.poll.interval.ms = idle between polls*2, the record takes millisecods to get processed, we also set the max.poll.records to 10

Comment: Also as i said in edit 2, when i decreased the idle between polls to 10 sec, the rebalance stopped

Comment: Hmmm - something else must be going on - there is logic in the container that ensures that the idle between polls is never greater than `max.poll.interval.ms - timeSinceLastPoll - 5000` (5 seconds less to avoid a race). I will see if I can reproduce your condition.

Comment: I edited the question with the code snippet i'm using. Also the problem is not visible on testing env. i think it might be because on testing i have only 1 host, but on prod. i've 5 hosts

Comment: Are you sure the rebalance is caused by this? I don't see how it can happen. As I said, even if the interval is incorrectly set at a too-large value, we adjust it down to ensure we don't exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: i noticed this log "About to close the idle connection from 105 due to being idle for 540012 millis" before the rebalance, after searching  i found this property connections.max.idle.ms is set to 9 min, but i dont know why the connection was idle for that time

Comment: Looking at the `kafka-clients`, it looks like that is controlled by `connections.max.idle.ms`. There's a comment in `ConsumerConfig` `/* default is set to be a bit lower than the server default (10 min), to avoid both client and server closing connection at same time */` - it is set to 9 minutes by default so with an idlebetween of only 5 mins, that shouldn't kick in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219828/discussion-between-user1928473-and-gary-russell).

Comment: @GaryRussell
I've got the same continuous rebalancing problem due to idleBetweenPolls param with 4 pods in OpenShift.
Have you found the possible cause of this problem?

Comment: Ask a new question showing code, configuration and logs.

Comment: @GaryRussell asked new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404868/spring-for-apache-kafka-idlebetweenpolls-param-leads-to-continuous-rebalance

Answer (score 1):

Though Gary Russel's answer is correct, I want to elaborate a bit on this answer.

You see, `max.poll.interval.ms` represents the max amount of time that can pass between polls of the consumer. If the particular consumer *A* in this specific consumer group *B* is configured to poll records from the broker each 15s for instance, and setting `max.poll.interval.ms` is configured to 12s on the client, then, once 12s will pass, **the broker will decide that the consumer *A* is dead**, because the consumer *A* was not yet managed to poll, and the broker will remove this consumer *A* from the consumer group, which will, of course, trigger the partition rebalance.

So that is why

> **time to process last polled records** + **idle between polls** must be less than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

is a valid statement, since **time to process last polled records** + **idle between polls** equals the pull period, and in plain English it just means - *you should poll before timeout*

As a side note, `max.poll.interval.ms` is not the only thing that is used to indicate consumer failures. There is also [session.timeout.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#session-timeout-ms) setting, used in conjunction with [heartbeat.interval.ms](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#heartbeat-interval-ms). Just beware that misconfiguring these 2 settings can also lead to continuous rebalance of the partitions. That's out of the topic, I will not explain it here, but FYI there is a [very good answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39759329/16785907) about how all these settings live together, I highly suggest you take a look at it.

Have a nice day)