# Spring for Apache Kafka idleBetweenPolls param leads to continuous rebalance

Tags: spring-kafka

I've got Spring for Apache Kafka `KafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean configured with `idleBetweenPolls` param:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Event>> dlqKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
   Map<String, Object> kafkaConfigs
) {
    kafkaConfigs.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 60 * 1000);
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event2Extended<?>>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConfigs));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(5 * 60 * 1000L);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

My application is running in 4 pods in OpenShift and I have a continuous rebalancing problem.

Problem logs by `o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator`are:

1. Attempt to heartbeat with Generation...and group instance id Optional.empty failed due to UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID, resetting generation
2. Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
3. (Re-)joining group

But the problem disappears if I remove:

```java
factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(5 * 60 * 1000L);
```

Comment: You need to show full logs with time stamps. Also set the container property commitLogLevel to INFO. Also specify versions.

Comment: My Spring Boot version is 2.4.4, Spring for Apache Kafka version is 2.6.7 and kafka-clients is 2.6.1
Unfortunately, because of my company security constraints I can't publish full logs but I could send you particular logs that can help

Comment: Without detailed logs with timestamps, showing the actual consumer config, the last commit, and the rebalance, nobody can help you.

Comment: Make sure the max poll interval is actually applied. See the INFO log for the consumer. The way you are setting it is a little strange. It is hard to tell what it does.

Comment: I noticed this behavior on startup where the target destination of the applied idleBetweenPolls initially sleeps apparently before polling any records.